# How can I position my header at the top of the page and have it come after the content in source order?

Tags: css

We are creating a `<div>`-based web design. We have created one div for header, one div for content and one div for footer. We wish that in the source code, the content div should come first but while viewing, the header should be seen at the top of the page.

How can we achieve this in CSS?

Comment: Why do you require your content div source to be at the top?

Answer (score 2):

set header div `position` is `absolute`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
.nin
{
width:940px;
margin:auto;
}
.heade
{
background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #E0E0E0;
border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
height: 50px;
position: absolute;
top: 0;
width: 940px;
}
.heade h1   {  line-height: 0; }
.fod
{
height:50px;
border-radius:5px;
background:#E0E0E0;
}
.mid
{
margin-top:75px;
height:500px;
    background:#FFFFFF;
border-style:solid;
border-radius:5px;
border-width:2px;
}
.left
{
border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
border-style: solid;
border-width: 2px;
float: left;
height: 343px;
margin-left: 5px;
margin-top: 5px;
width: 450px;
}
.right {
border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
border-style: solid;
border-width: 2px;
float: right;
height: 125px;
margin-right: 5px;
margin-top: 220px;
width: 461px;
}
.bottom
{
border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
border-style: dashed;
border-width: 2px;
height: 135px;
margin-left: 2px;
margin-top: 356px;
width: 925px;
}
</style>
</head >
<body>
<div class="nin">

<div class="mid">
<div class="left"> 
    <ul>
<li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="#news">News</a></li>
<li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
<li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
</ul>

</div>
<div class="right"> 

<p>It is a coontent box one</p>
</div>
<div class="bottom">
<p>It is a content box two</p>
  <a href="http://www.iprofile.net/">Iprofile</a>
</div>
</div>
<div class="heade">
<h1>
<p style="text-align:center">This is header</p>
</h1>
</div>
<div class="fod">
<div>
<h1>
<p style="text-align:center">This is footer</p>
</h1>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks and sorry Mr. Selva as per your idea the header is stable. But my need is not that..

Comment: Thank you @Selvamani Your answer was helpful for me for a different task. :)

Answer (score 2):

1. Set `padding-top` on the `<body>` element to be the same as the height of your header. This will move your content `<div>` down, and leave enough space for the header.

   If your header doesn’t have a fixed height in pixels, you could use `em`s for the top padding instead, as this will adapt if the user changes their font size. But you’ll still have to have a good idea what content will be in the header, and how tall it will be.
2. Set the header `<div>` to `position: absolute; top: 0;` to remove it from the normal layout flow, and position it at the top of the page. You’ll probably want to set a value for `left` too, but that’ll depend on your specific layout.

Comment: Thanks Paul, any idea about position: absolute; top: 0;

in responsive design?

Comment: .seconddiv {
 position:absolute;
 width:100%;
 left:0px;
 top:45px;

}


I am using the above code. In responsive design, when I give 45px some of the <div> elements are overlapping. How to handle it?

Comment: @Joshua: That hasn’t helped clarify your question about responsive design. I’m afraid I don’t understand what you’re asking me.

Comment: @Joshua: I’m not quite clear on what you mean by the phrase “in responsive design”. Responsive design means writing different CSS for different screen resolutions. If you’ve got a problem with some code that you’ve written, it might be better to ask a new question that shows us the code you’ve got and the layout it results in (jsfiddle.net is good for sharing code), and what layout you actually want. Feel free to leave a comment here linking to the new question.

Comment: @Joshua: right, but without seeing your HTML and the rest of your CSS, I’ve got no idea how the other `<div>`s are positioned, and thus no idea why they’re overlapping. It sounds like you’ve got a specific question about some code you’ve written. The best way to get it answered is to ask a new question about it, including the code.